# How do you keep a list of objects in C# that does not interfere with garbage collection?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I'm trying to maintain a list of objects in a Manager class in C#. Basically a consumer class registers with the Manager class and the manager class maintains a collection of references to the consumer class. Now as far as my (limited) understanding of GC goes, keeping a reference to the consumer class will prevent the consumer class being garbage collected.

What I am after is a way of maintaining a reference to the class in the manager class that might or might not point to the consumer class (in a determinable way) depending on whether it has been garbage collected. How does one do this in c#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx) class to create a "weak" reference to an object. That is, the object will be a candidate for collection as long as it is only referenced by *strong* references.

If it's not referenced by strong references (only weak ones) then the garbage collector will consider it a candidate for garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks. That's a pretty useful addition to the arsenal. Thanks people!

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [weak references](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-weak-references).